# jq select error: "Cannot index string with string <object>"

Tags: json, jq

command:

```
cat test.json | jq -r '.[] | select(.input[] | .["$link"] | contains("randomtext1")) | .id'
```

I was expecting to have both entries (`a` and `b`) to show up since they both contains `randomtext1`

Instead, I got the following output message:

```
a

jq: error (at <stdin>:22): Cannot index string with string "$link"
```

From some digging I understand that the issue is likely caused by the following object/value pair in the `a` entry:

```
"someotherobj": "123"
```

because it does not contain the object `$link` and the filter in the command expects to see `$link` in all objects under the `input` so it errors out before the command has a chance to search in the `b` entry.

What I really want is to be able to search for any entries that have at least one `"$link": "randomtext1"` pair under `input`. Is there a fuzzier search feature allowing me to achieve this?

I tried to use two `contains` hoping it will just pipe things through:

```
jq -r '.[] | select(.input[] | contains(["$link"]) | contains("randomtext1")) | .id'
```

but it did not like that at all..

the test.json file:

```
[
  {
    "input": {
      "obj1": {
        "$link": "randomtext1"
      },
      "obj2": {
        "$link": "randomtext2"
      },
      "someotherobj": "123"
    },
    "id": "a"
  },
  {
    "input": {
      "obj3": {
        "$link": "randomtext1"
      },
      "obj4": {
        "$link": "randomtext2"
      }
    },
    "id": "b"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I really want is to be able to search for any entries that have at least one "$link": "randomtext1" pair under input.

The key word here, both in the question and the following answer, is `any`:

```
.[]
| select( any(.input[];
              type=="object" and has("$link") and (.["$link"] | index("randomtext1"))))
| .id
```

Of course if you require the key's value to be "randomtext1", you'd write `.["$link"] == "randomtext1"`.

Comment: Thanks @peak. The command works well with the example:  
`cat test.json | jq -r '.[] | select( any(.input[]; has("$link") and (.["$link"] | index("randomtext1") ) ) ) | .id'`


I don't know if there is some cache mechanism or my computer. If I change the values in the test.txt file, for testing purpose, an inconsistent error "Cannot check whether string has a string key" occurs:
`change both "randomtext1" to "randomtext3"`

Comment: ... or `change the first "randomtext1" to "randomtext3"`.

Comment: Same issue with `select( any(.input[]; has("$link") and (.["$link"]=="randomtext1" ) ) )` It seems like the command just errors out at the first entry if it does not fulfill the filter criteria. What I want is for it to show the entry that has randomtext1 text and ignore any entry that doesn't.

Comment: Does the updated answer which checks type=="object" meet your requirements?

Comment: yes!
`cat test.json | jq -r '.[] | select( any(.input[]; type=="object" and has("$link") and (.["$link"]=="randomtext1"))) | .id'`
Thanks!