# How to filter for key pairs in an object array (json and jq)

Tags: arrays, json, object, filter, jq

This is a follow-up on 
[jq select error: "Cannot index string with string <object>"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55662024/jq-select-error-cannot-index-string-with-string-object)

Previously, I can filter the entries in a json file that has the target objects with the following command and filter:

```
[{
    "input": {
        "obj1": {
            "$link": "randomtext1"
        },
        "id": "a"
    }
}]
```

`jq -r '.[] | select( any(.input[]; type=="object" and has("$link") and (.["$link"]=="randomtext1")))|.id'`
will give "a"

How can I filter if now the key "$link" and its value "randomtext1" belong to an array?

```
[{
    "input": {
        "obj1": [{
            "$link": "randomtext1"
        }],
        "id": "a"
    }
}]
```

(I still want to be able to find "a" as the result)

Example .json:

```
[
  {
    "input": {
      "obj1": [{
        "$link": "randomtext1"
      }],
      "obj2": [{
        "$link": "randomtext2"
      }],
      "someotherobj": "123"
    },
    "id": "a"
  },
  {
    "input": {
      "obj3": {
        "$link": "randomtext1"
      },
      "obj4": {
        "$link": "randomtext2"
      }
    },
    "id": "b"
  }
]
```

I am hoping to find both a and b with "randomtext1" keyword but only got b with the same filter from the previous case after obj1 and obj2 have been "shielded/masked" by the array brackets in the example json file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add an "or" to cover the new possibility:

```
.[]
| select( any(.input[];
              (type=="object" and (has("$link") and (.["$link"]=="randomtext1")))
              or (type=="array" and any(.[];
                                        type == "object" and (has("$link") and (.["$link"]=="randomtext1")))) ))
|.id
```

### ... or more readably:

```
def relevant($txt):
  type == "object" and has("$link") and (.["$link"]==$txt);

.[]
| select( any(.input[];
              relevant("randomtext1")
              or (type=="array" and any(.[]; relevant("randomtext1"))) ))
|.id
```

Comment: Thanks! All these filter syntax is forming a big ball of spaghetti in my brain nicely. At least I have a template for the similar logic I try to do and for that I am grateful.